# Clearing the buffer used by stdout

Tags: c++, stdout

In a C++ program, I want to have all the logging appear in both terminal and a file. The program has lots of printf() usage, and removing them is not feasible.

To achieve this, I've set the stdout and stderr to use buffers of my own with setvbuf(). Each time my log function is run, it saves a copy of the data from stdout to the log file, then flushes stdout and sterr. But after flush(), it seems that the buffers aren't actually cleared; unless I memset() the entire buffer, parts of the stdout data appear multiple times. 
Output in the terminal is correct.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

char stdoutBuffer[100000];

void log(const std::string& msg, FILE* file) {
    fwrite(stdoutBuffer, 1, strlen(stdoutBuffer), file); //write data accumulated in stdout to file

    fwrite(msg.c_str(), 1, msg.size(), file); //save our own stuff to file

    puts(msg.c_str()); //for completeness put our own log to the console
    fflush(stdout);

    //stdoutBuffer[0] = 0; //reduces duplication
    //memset(stdoutBuffer, 0, sizeof(stdoutBuffer)); //seems to be correct
}


int main() {
    fflush(stdout);
    setvbuf(stdout, stdoutBuffer, _IOFBF, sizeof(stdoutBuffer));

    FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "wb");

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("log nr %d\n", count);
        count += 1;

        char buf[100];
        sprintf(buf, "log nr %d\n", count);
        log(std::string(buf), file);
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

Actual contents of the file:

```
log nr 0
log nr 1
log nr 2
log nr 1

log nr 3
log nr 4
log nr 3

log nr 5
```

Expected contents (achieved with the full memset):

```
log nr 0
log nr 1
log nr 2
log nr 3
log nr 4
log nr 5
```

Comment: Please show more code, including how you write a message, what output you get and what output you expected. To get good answers, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to read from `stdoutBuffer` after the call to `setvbuf`

Comment: It also isn't valid to assume it is null-terminated.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed all Qt stuff from there to make this easily compilable.

Comment: @M.M - You should post this as an answer - it renders moot all other discussion of the problem.

Comment: @Jeremy well - possibly true but also there are some cases where something is undefined due to it not being possible to define it without annoying existing implementations, and on a particular platform it might be safe to rely on the behaviour. I don't really know any more about OP's situation than anyone else

Comment: The behaviour seems consistently the same on both Debian and Windows, so I'll have to accept this as the correct answer.
However, what would be the best method to save stdout and stderr to the file, and also have the messages keep their chronological order as much as possible?